# Access index of the parent ng-repeat from child ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use the index of the parent list (foos) as an argument to a function call in the child list (foos.bars).

I found a post where someone recommends using $parent.$index, but `$index` is not a property of `$parent`.

How can I access the index of the parent `ng-repeat`?

```
<div ng-repeat="f in foos">
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="b in foos.bars">
      <a ng-click="addSomething($parent.$index)">Add Something</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work correctly for me.

I've wrote a plunker to show it working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BenCDh4NUGPPHKWGsGMr?p=preview

Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Thank you for that. It led me to find my issue was a bug in my markup.

Comment: @Coder1, please consider deleting this question.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I did consider it last night, but thought it would be helpful to others searching for how to do this, so I left it.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep it, please add an answer and accept it (so this question doesn't remain on the "unanswered" list).

Answer (score 285, accepted):

My example code was correct and the issue was something else in my actual code. Still, I know it was difficult to find examples of this so I'm answering it in case someone else is looking.

```
<div ng-repeat="f in foos">
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="b in foos.bars">
      <a ng-click="addSomething($parent.$index)">Add Something</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also- this threw me for a while. If there is an data-ng-switch directive within your code, you'll need to go up an additional scope level- ($parent.$parent.$index). Not pretty, I know.

Comment: Agreed. I needed to pass $parent.$parent.$index to my controller function to get the correct value but then bind my ng-show to $parent.$index.  Seems like an angular bug to me

Comment: Can I do something like this if I have one Collection repeat along with ng-repeat?Apparently it is returning undefined doing the same

Comment: Just to add - you need an additional $parent even if you have an `ng-if` in the code as I just found out.

Comment: @PlastyGrove Thank you for pointing out that ``ng-if`` requires and additional ``$parent`` reference. Saved me some headache.

Answer (score 220):

According to ng-repeat docs http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat, you can store the key or array index in the variable of your choice. `(indexVar, valueVar) in values`

so you can write

```
<div ng-repeat="(fIndex, f) in foos">
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="b in foos.bars">
      <a ng-click="addSomething(fIndex)">Add Something</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One level up is still quite clean with $parent.$index but several parents up, things can get messy.

Note: `$index` will continue to be defined at each scope, it is not replaced by `fIndex`.

Comment: I don't understand the Note. Isn't the whole point of this question because that isn't true?

Comment: This should be the validated answer as it's cleaner than the `$parent.$index` one

Comment: @adam-beck I think they mean that when using this `(fIndex, f)` method, $index will still be defined (not omitted) - so the index becomes accessible as both `$index` and `fIndex`.

Comment: For my case, using `$index` does not work, but adding the `fIndex` does. I have not a single clue as to *why* `$index` does not work (it does in other places in my code), but after struggling for several days I stopped caring when I found this answer. It is also a bit more readable when you have multiple `ng-repeat`s IMO.

Comment: @Krøllebølle the reason it works the way you see it is that each `ng-repeat` iteration creates its own scope, which also defines its own `$index`, overwriting the parent's `$index`. If you include a `{{$index}}` right above or below the innermost `ng-repeat`-ed element, you'll see the parent's value, and putting it inside the innermost `ng-repeat`-ed element will show you the child's. Using the approach in this answer just assigns the parent index to a variable whose name you've chosen (`fIndex`) so it won't get overwritten by a child scope.

Comment: The variable doesn't get updated if you delete an element which was in the repeat array. $index and $parent.$index is always the safe choice

Answer (score 47):

Take a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20911384/1432478).
By aliasing `$index` we do not have to write crazy stuff like `$parent.$parent.$index`.

---

Way more elegant solution whan `$parent.$index` is using [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit):

```
<ul ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index">
    <li  class="section_title {{section.active}}" >
        {{section.name}}
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li class="tutorial_title {{tutorial.active}}" ng-click="loadFromMenu(sectionIndex)" ng-repeat="tutorial in section.tutorials">
            {{tutorial.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/knwGEnOsAWLhLieKVItS?p=info

Comment: also it's safer! if you add an ng-if inside the loop, you get the $index messed, check:
http://plnkr.co/52oIhLfeXXI9ZAynTuAJ

Comment: I had to do sectionIndex = $parent.$index

Comment: The variable doesn't get updated if you delete an element which was in the repeat array. $index and $parent.$index is always the safe choice

Answer (score 12):

You can also get control of grand parent index by the following code

```
$parent.$parent.$index
```

Comment: This works well for my project. Thank you for providing awesome solution!

Comment: This is not extensible, apparently.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is somewhat of an example of feature envy and obviously problematic many cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use  use $parent.$index .where parent will represent object of parent repeating object .

Answer (score 0):

$parent doesn't work if there are multiple parents. instead of that we can define a parent index variable in init and use it

```
<div data-ng-init="parentIndex = $index" ng-repeat="f in foos">
  <div>
    <div data-ng-init="childIndex = $index" ng-repeat="b in foos.bars">
      <a ng-click="addSomething(parentIndex)">Add Something</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see answer from vucalur here it also mentions this.  In general this is the correct way to go IMO and generally only proper use for ng-init.  Any time people are reaching up to $parent you are asking for trouble when the context of your code changes.