# Get html attribute through $scope in angularjs

Tags: dom, recursion, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Alright, so I'm making a recursive list in AngularJS using ng-include and ng-repeat, something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="text" ng-click="DivClick()">
    <ul>
        <li id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="data in layer" ng-include="'recursion.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="recursion.html">
<textarea myd-keypress cols="63" rows="1">{{data.content}}</textarea>
<input type="text" myd-numbers value="{{data.price}}"></input>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in data.layer" ng-include="'recursion.html'" id="{{$parent.$attr('id') + '-' + $index}}"></li>
</ul>
```

But of course, it doesn't work. So basically what I need is that every < li> element in dom has id that corresponds like this:

```
 0
 1
   1-0
   1-1
     1-1-0
   1-2
   1-3
 2
   2-0
```

so that every new < li> has id that equals "id of its parent" + "-$index".
What I know that will work is that scope.layer[] and its layer descendants contain a field that will save ID of the < li> and display it, but I want to avoid saving that extra field in the DB because solution to this is really simple (as shown in the example), but I can't get over syntax. Any suggestions?

Comment: be fairly simple to recursively loop through all branches of the `layer` array and add an ID property to each element object and output that new property with angular expession in the markup. Provide sample of `layer` data

Answer (score 0):

Before passing data to `$scope.label` you could loop over it with function that recursively loops branches and adds an `id` property

```
var data = [{
    name: 'foo',
    children: [{
        name: 'foo child',
        children: [{
            name: 'foo child grandchild'
        }, {
            name: 'foo child grandchild2'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'foo child2'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'bar'
}]

function createID(arr, parentID) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var id = (i + 1).toString();
        var thisID = parentID ? parentID + '-' + id : id;
        arr[i].id = thisID;
        if (arr[i].children) {
             createID(arr[i].children, thisID)
         }
    }
 }
createID(data, null)
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/z4RPz/

Comment: This was my initial idea, but this means that I'd have either one extra field for every level of recursion and bloat my db, or a whole new structure storing only IDs which I'd have to initialize when my json structure loads up and it'd be complicated. There's no way to simply reach "id" property of < li> in parent scope?

Comment: can't access a value that hasn't been created. WHat `id` value are you talking about in parent scope?

Comment: for example, in parent iteratation of LI tags each LI has its own ID and I need those IDs somehow. If not that, how can I create my own functions to call with {{ }} brackets? I thought it was new service but I can't get a grip on it quite well... I'll work on it more tomorrow.

Comment: not clear what ID you are talking about. Is it in your data? If so provide sample of data. You implied in question that not ID existed. What is wrong with solution I provided? property is avaiailable for use with `{{item.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're wanting to do is reach up and grab the `$index` from the parent element.

You can do that using `$parent.$index` - or in this case, it may be `$parent.$parent.$index`, as you're using `ng-repeat -> ng-include -> ng-repeat`

See this answer for more information on a similar situation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15257501/317180

Comment: But the thing is that this will work for one level only, meaning that if I need to get an id of a grandchild, for example 2-3-1, I'll get 3-1 because I'm only reaching first parent.