# using ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm developing a page where I need to show some boxes (using `ng-repeat`) that contains info of channels and where it will be shown (which are cities).

The problem I am facing is when I repeat the second `ng-repeat`:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" ng-init="nitsCh = [objsCh[$index].nit]">
```

This should get the $index of first ng-repeat and create a new array with the places the channels will be shown. And it does exactly that. But, when I apply the second ng-repeat using this array, it doesn't work properly.

Said that my html looks like this (PS: I need to use the index value instead of `objCh.name` because I place these boxes into columns)

```
<div class="box box-solid box-default" ng-repeat="(indexO, objCh) in objsCh track by indexO" ng-if="indexO%4==0  && indexO<=10">
  <div class="box-header"> 
    <div class="pull-left"> 
      <img src="dist/img/channels/{{ objsCh[indexO].pic }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Alterar logo do canal"> 
      <h3 class="box-title">{{ objsCh[(indexO)].name }}</h3> 
    </div> 
    <div class="box-tools pull-right"> 
      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Adicionar ou Remover NIT"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="box-body"> 
    <table class="table table-condensed" ng-init="nitsCh = [objsCh[indexO].nit]"> 
      <tbody> 
        <tr> 
          <th style="width: 10px">#</th> 
          <th>Nit</th> 
        </tr> 
        <tr ng-repeat="(indexN,nitCh) in nitsCh track by indexN"> 
          <td>{{ objsCh[(indexO + 1)].nit[indexN].num }}</td>
          <td>{{ objsCh[(indexO + 1)].nit[indexN].name }}</td>
        </tr> 
      </tbody>
    </table> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

The JS file looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('appApp', []);
app.controller('ctrlApp', function($scope, $http) {

    var url = "includes/exibChNit.php";

    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        all = response;
        $scope.objsCh = all.channels;
    });
});
```

And the json file (that php create) looks like this:

```
{
    "channels": [{
        "id": "1",
        "sid": "1",
        "name": "Channel",
        "pic": "channel.jpg",
        "crc32": "A1g423423B2",
        "special": "0",
        "url": "",
        "key": "",
        "type": "",
        "city": [{
            "num": "1",
            "name": "S�o Paulo"
        }, {
            "num": "2",
            "name": "Rio de Janeiro"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "sid": "2",
        "name": "CHannel 1",
        "pic": "channel.jpg",
        "crc32": "A1F5534234B2",
        "special": "0",
        "url": "",
        "key": "",
        "type": "",
        "city": [{
            "num": "1",
            "name": "S�o Paulo"
        }, {
            "num": "2",
            "name": "Rio de Janeiro"
        }]
    }]
}
```

When I try this it works:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" ng-init="nitsCh = [objsCh[($parent.$index + 1)].nit]">
```

But I can't make it this way because the json nodes will be dynamic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Minus 1 for you:  for adding an edit that includes my answer of `$parent.$index` and not mentioning it.

Comment: this is way overcomplicated. Explain what you mean about not being able to use objects themselves due to columns. I've done lots of deep ng-repeat nesting without all the extra indexes you are using

Comment: Also can use `limitTo` filter instead of the `ng-if="indexO%4==0  && indexO<=10"`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`ng-repeat`'s create their own `$scope`.

So, for the inner ng-repeats, you have access to `$parent.$index`, where `$parent` is the parent scope of the current repeat block.

For ex:

```
<ul ng-repeat="section in sections">
  <li>
      {{section.name}}
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li ng-click="loadFromMenu($parent.$index)" ng-repeat="tutorial in section.tutorials">
          {{tutorial.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/hOfAldNevxKzZQlxFfBn?p=preview

(simplified from this answer [passing 2 $index values within nested ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256600/passing-2-index-values-within-nested-ng-repeat))

Comment: Didn't work. I tried to insert it here: 
<table class="table table-condensed" ng-init="nitsCh = [objsCh[($parent.$index + 1)].nit]"> but if I do it this way it works: <table class="table table-condensed" ng-init="nitsCh = [0,1]">

Comment: Maybe a plunkr would help. Its very hard for me to process your variable names like `nitsCh` , `objsCh`, `indexN,nitCh`

Comment: I took the liberty of doing that for you, please updated plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/9IAcPfeZRUJQLF66xVPw?p=preview

Comment: If that still doesn't answer your question, you need to explain what you are trying to do with the `ng-init` block, because your language is very cryptic.

Comment: loadFromMenu should really pass the parent object as argument to make it even simper

Comment: Agree but that is proof of concept. OP question does not even have a click function

Comment: saved me! Thanks a lot