# Nested ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an value like that my problem is i don't know how much nested that dummy array object so how to use ng-repeat that print all dummy array object

```
demo: [{
    id: 1,
    dummy: [
        {
            id: 1,
            dummy: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    dummy: [
                        {
                            id: 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: see this nice answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108946/how-to-put-ng-repeat-inside-ng-repeat-for-n-number-of-times/37109091#37109091

Comment: its just handle two level only

Comment: Not sure but you can create a directive which will print current element and call itself with new dummy value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this. as this answers: [How to put ng-repeat inside ng-repeat for n number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108946/how-to-put-ng-repeat-inside-ng-repeat-for-n-number-of-times/37109091#37109091) 
and [How can I make recursive templates in AngularJS when using nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661289/how-can-i-make-recursive-templates-in-angularjs-when-using-nested-objects)

```js
var app = angular.module("app",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.demo = [{
    id: 1,
    dummy: [
        {
            id: 1,
            dummy: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    dummy: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                             dummy: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                             dummy:[]
                        }
                       ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="dummy.html">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="d in demo" >
        <div >{{d.id}}</div>
        <div ng-show="d.dummy.length"  ng-include=" 'dummy.html' " onload="demo = d.dummy"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>
  <div ng-include=" 'dummy.html'" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Walfrat but i tested this on chrome!

Comment: ok i totally don't know why, now it's showing ... i removed the old comment saying 'not working' so people won't stop on it.

Comment: Thank u its working fine now i accept your answer but i have one question What if i need to show it in descending order means the last dummy array object show on first. is it possible?