# Recursion with ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following data structure for items in my sidemenu, in an Angular app based on a paid-for web site theme. The data structure is my own, and the menu is derived from the original menu view with all items in the `ul` hard coded.

In `SidebarController.js`:

```
$scope.menuItems = [
    {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "#/dashboard.html",
        "text": "Dashboard"
    },
    {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "javascript:;",
        "text": "AngularJS Features",
        "subItems": [
            {
                "href": "#/ui_bootstrap.html",
                "text": " UI Bootstrap"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "javascript:;",
        "text": "jQuery Plugins",
        "subItems": [
            {
                "href": "#/form-tools",
                "text": " Form Tools"
            },
            {
                "isNavItem": true,
                "href": "javascript:;",
                "text": " Datatables",
                "subItems": [
                    {
                        "href": "#/datatables/managed.html",
                        "text": " Managed Datatables"
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Then I have the following partial view bound to that model as follows:

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" ng-class="{'page-sidebar-menu-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-class="{'start': item.isStart, 'nav-item': item.isNavItem}">
        <a href="{{item.href}}" ng-class="{'nav-link nav-toggle': item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0}">
            <span class="title">{{item.text}}</span>
        </a>
        <ul ng-if="item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0" class="sub-menu">
            <li ng-repeat="item in item.subItems" ng-class="{'start': item.isStart, 'nav-item': item.isNavItem}">
                <a href="{{item.href}}" ng-class="{'nav-link nav-toggle': item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0}">
                    <span class="title">{{item.text}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE** There may be `$scope` properties in the view bindings you don't see in the model, or vice versa, but that is because I have edited them for brevity.
Now because the second level `li` doesn't also contain a conditional `ul` for its own `subItems`, the sub-items under the `Datatable` menu item don't get rendered.

How can I create a view or template, or both, that will bind recursively to the model, so that all sub-items of all sub-items are rendered? This will normally only be up to four levels.

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269152/nested-ng-repeat-angularjs/37270877#37270877

Comment: `item in item.subitems` this is really bad to debug, inside second ng-repeat `item` is both item from first and second repeat, rename it to subItem or anything but this [EDIT] when I copied your code into plunker it worked straight away: http://plnkr.co/edit/P8zJWJO9jXtKu2Yt97TR?p=preview

Comment: @maurycy I have only temporarily kept the same name for the iteration variable because when I eventually get to a recursive binding scenario, the template will only use one variable, with one name, `item`. I am not doing any debugging, and the template works as is, except for the second level sub-items.

Comment: Did you checked my plunk link? The issue must be somewhere else, can you try and reproduce it on plunk or any other similar tool?

Comment: @maurycy No, it took me 1 second to see your plunk doesn't work. Under the `Datatables` menu item, there is a sub-item called `Managed Datatables`. This does not display in your plunker, and I don't expect it to. My view is not coded for recursion, and that is the whole point of this question: I'm asking how to code it recursively.

Comment: I'd say that you might need a custom directive that will handle it nicely, i'll think of the structure and post it later (i'm on scrum now ;))

Answer (score 16):

You can simply use **ng-include** to make a partial and call it recursively:
Partial should be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in item.subItems">
      <a href="{{item.href}}" ng-class="{'nav-link nav-toggle': item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0}">
          <span class="title">{{item.text}}</span>
      </a>
      <div ng-switch on="item.subItems.length > 0">
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
          <div ng-init="subItems = item.subItems;" ng-include="'partialSubItems.html'"></div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And your html:

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" ng-class="{'page-sidebar-menu-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-class="{'start': item.isStart, 'nav-item': item.isNavItem}">
        <a href="{{item.href}}" ng-class="{'nav-link nav-toggle': item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0}">
            <span class="title">{{item.text}}</span>
        </a>
        <ul ng-if="item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0" class="sub-menu">

            <li ng-repeat="item in item.subItems" ng-class="{'start': item.isStart, 'nav-item': item.isNavItem}">
                 <a href="{{item.href}}" ng-class="{'nav-link nav-toggle': item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0}">
                    <span class="title">{{item.text}}</span>
                </a>

                 <div ng-switch on="item.subItems.length > 0">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">
                      <div ng-init="subItems = item.subItems;" ng-include="'newpartial.html'"></div>  
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/9HJZzV4cgacK92xxQOr0?p=preview

Comment: Have issues with updating the model, doesn't update the ng-include due to the ng-init call, any ideas on this?

Comment: hello, @edencorbin I am the as same situation as you not able to update the model in ng-include. so here have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this simply by including a **javascript template**  and template include using **ng-include**

define javascript template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu.html">...</script>
```

and include it like:

```
<div ng-if="item.subItems.length" ng-include="'menu.html'"></div>
```

**Example**: In this example I used basic html without any class you can use classes as you need. I just shown basic recursion structure.

In **html**:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
      <a href="{{item.href}}">
        <span>{{item.text}}</span>
      </a>
      <div ng-if="item.subItems.length" ng-include="'menu.html'"></div>
    </li>
</ul>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu.html">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in item.subItems">
        <a href="{{item.href}}">
          <span>{{item.text}}</span>
        </a>
        <div ng-if="item.subItems.length" ng-include="'menu.html'"></div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</script>
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/C5tm7XMuZbV8ONqWOJcb?p=preview)**

Answer (score 7):

If your intention is to draw an menu with indefinite level of sub items, probably a good implementation is to make a **directive**.

With a directive you will be able to assume more control over your menu.

I created a basic exepmle with full **recursion**, on with you can see an easy implementation of more than one menu on the same page and more than 3 levels on one of the menus, see this [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2vigMK2aMwQDQwvZKro8?p=preview).

**Code:**

```
.directive('myMenu', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      template:
        '<li ng-repeat="item in List" ' +
        'ng-class="{\'start\': item.isStart, \'nav-item\': item.isNavItem}">' +
        '<a href="{{item.href}}" ng-class="{\'nav-link nav-toggle\': item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0}">'+
        '<span class="title"> {{item.text}}</span> ' +
        '</a>'+
        '<ul my-menu="item.subItems" class="sub-menu"> </ul>' +
        '</li>',
      link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        //this List will be scope invariant so if you do multiple directive 
        //menus all of them wil now what list to use
        scope.List = $parse(attrs.myMenu)(scope);
      }
    }
}])
```

**Markup:**

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu" 
    data-keep-expanded="false" 
    data-auto-scroll="true" 
    data-slide-speed="200" 
    ng-class="{'page-sidebar-menu-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}"
    my-menu="menuItems">
</ul>
```

**Edit**

**Some notes**

When it comes to make the decision about `ng-include`(that i think is a fair enough solution) or `.directive`, you have to ask yourself at least two questions first. Does my code fragment going to need some logic? If not you could as well just go for the ng-include.
But if you are going to put more logic in the fragment making it customizable, make changes to the element or attrs (DOM) manipulation, you should go for directive.
As well one point that make me fell more confortable with the directive is reusability of the code you write, since in my example you can give controll more and make a more generic one i assume you should go for that if your project is big and needs to grow. So the second question does my code going to be reusable?

A reminder for a clean directive is that instead of `template` you could use the `templateUrl`, and you can give a file to feed the html code that is currently in  the `template`.

If you are using 1.5+ you can now choose to use `.component`. Component is a wrapper arroud `.direcitve` that has a lot less boilerplate code. Here you can see the diference.

```
                  Directive                Component

bindings          No                       Yes (binds to controller)
bindToController  Yes (default: false)     No (use bindings instead)
compile function  Yes                      No
controller        Yes                      Yes (default function() {})
controllerAs      Yes (default: false)     Yes (default: $ctrl)
link functions    Yes                      No
multiElement      Yes                      No
priority          Yes                      No
require           Yes                      Yes
restrict          Yes                      No (restricted to elements only)
scope             Yes (default: false)     No (scope is always isolate)
template          Yes                      Yes, injectable
templateNamespace Yes                      No
templateUrl       Yes                      Yes, injectable
terminal          Yes                      No
transclude        Yes (default: false)     Yes (default: false)
```

Source angular guide for [**component**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

**Edit**

As sugested by Mathew Berg if you want not to include the ul element if the list of subItems is empty you can change the ul to this something like this `<ul ng-if="item.subItems.length>0" my-menu="item.subItems" class="sub-menu"> </ul>`

Comment: Thanks. I would hate for the level of sub-items to actually become infinite, but without knowing how many I should handle, I'm aiming high. I'll check the directive approach later today.

Comment: Nice to hear, if something kick in just tell me, and i will take a look to that.

Comment: So basically this directive is simply a means to give me a recursive template? I'm working in a massive, paid for, framework with STACKS of other JS and Angular code, so when I use this in the real page, the page doesn't load, with no error code.

Comment: Yes, if the that structure is ok it should work as intended. It is possible to you to show how did you implement this directive the name you give it if you are inject it in the module that is used on the samr page as were you implement the menu and the version of angular that you are using? So I can try discover what is the issue with this implementation?

Comment: Only issue with this is the extra `ul` dom element that will be unused if there are no sub items. Maybe hide it behind an if pivoting off the length of subItems.

Comment: @MathewBerg added.

Answer (score 4):

After reviewing these options I found this article very clean/helpful for an ng-include approach that handles model changes well: http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

In summary:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
    {{ category.title }}
    <ul ng-if="category.categories">
        <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

then

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make recursion in Angular, I would love to use the basic feature of angularJS and i.e directive.

index.html

```
<rec-menu menu-items="menuItems"></rec-menu>
```

recMenu.html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.menuItems">
    <a ng-href="{{item.href}}">
      <span ng-bind="item.text"></span>
    </a>
    <div ng-if="item.menuItems && item.menuItems.length">
      <rec-menu menu-items="item.menuItems"></rec-menu>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

recMenu.html

```
angular.module('myApp').component('recMenu', {
  templateUrl: 'recMenu.html',
  bindings: {
    menuItems: '<'
  }
});
```

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qf54m0v3Wc6vZHuHdIPy?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Rahul Arora's answer is good, see this [blog post](http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates) for a similar example. The one change I would make is to use a component instead of ng-include. For an example see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZnjaHgK1kSzVbw7rlBOR?p=preview):

```
app
  .component('recursiveItem', {
    bindings: {
      item: '<'
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: 'newpartial.html'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using templates with `ng-include` or writing your own directive, I would suggest that you consider using an existing tree component implementation.
The reason is that from your description, that's exactly what you need. You have a hierarchical tree-like data structure that you want to display. It sounds obvious to me that you need a tree component.

Take a look at the following implementations (1st one preferable):
https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree
https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control
http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

All of the above require only that you do a minor adjustment to your model, or alternatively, use a proxy model.

If you do insist on implementing it by yourself (and no matter how you end up doing it, essentially you still will be implementing a tree component from scratch), I would suggest the directive approach as proposed in previous answers. Here's how I'd do it:

### JS

```
var app=angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.menuItems = [
    {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "#/dashboard.html",
        "text": "Dashboard"
    },
    {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "javascript:;",
        "text": "AngularJS Features",
        "subItems": [
            {
                "href": "#/ui_bootstrap.html",
                "text": " UI Bootstrap"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "javascript:;",
        "text": "jQuery Plugins",
        "subItems": [
            {
                "href": "#/form-tools",
                "text": " Form Tools"
            },
            {
                "isNavItem": true,
                "href": "javascript:;",
                "text": " Datatables",
                "subItems": [
                    {
                        "href": "#/datatables/managed.html",
                        "text": " Managed Datatables"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }];
});

app.directive('myMenu', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      menu: '='      
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var items = $compile('<my-menu-item ng-repeat="item in menu" menu-item="item"></my-menu-item>')(scope);

      elem.append(items);
    },
    template: '<ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" ng-class="{\'page-sidebar-menu-closed\': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}"></ul>'
  };
}]);

app.directive('myMenuItem', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      menuItem: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<li ng-class="{\'start\': item.isStart, \'nav-item\': item.isNavItem}"><a href="{{menuItem.href}}" ng-class="{\'nav-link nav-toggle\': menuItem.subItems && menuItem.subItems.length > 0}"> <span class="title">{{menuItem.text}}</span></a><my-menu menu="menuItem.subItems"></my-menu></li>'

  };
}]);
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-menu menu="menuItems"></my-menu>
</div>
```

Here's a working CodePen example: http://codepen.io/eitanfar/pen/oxZrpQ

### Some notes

1. You don't have to use 2 directives ("my-menu", "my-menu-item"), you can use just 1 (simply replace the ng-repeat of "my-menu-item" with its template), however, I think it's more coherent this way
2. The reason that the directive solution you tried didn't work (an educated guess, as I haven't debugged your attempt), is that it runs into an infinite loop. It does so, since linking happens for internal elements first. What I do in my suggested solution, is to postpone the linking of the sub items till after the linking of the parent menu is finished. Any disadvantages that this might have can be overcome by providing references in the scope (as I provide the 'menuItem' binding).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this exactly you are looking for -

You can achieve unlimited recursion by ng-repeat

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
{{data.name}}
<button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
<button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

```
  angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
        data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: []});
    };
    $scope.tree = [{name: "Node", nodes: []}];
}]);
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion can be very tricky. As things will get out of hand depending on how deep your tree is. Here is my suggestion:

```
.directive('menuItem', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            menuItem: '=menuItem'
        },
        templateUrl: 'menuItem.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element){
            var watcher = scope.$watch('menuItem.subItems', function(){
                if(scope.menuItem.subItems && scope.menuItem.subItems.length){
                    var subMenuItems = angular.element('<ul><li ng-repeat="subItem in menuItem.subItems" menu-item="subItem"></li></ul>')
                    $compile(subMenuItems)(scope);
                    element.append(subMenuItems);
                    watcher();
                }
            });
        }           
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<li>    
    <a ng-href="{{ menuItem.href }}">{{ menuItem.text }}</a>
</li>
```

This will make sure it doesn't create sub items repeatedly. You can see it working in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gnk8vcrv/

If you find it's crashing your app because you have a massive amount of lists (I'd be interested to see) you can hide the parts of the if statement besides the watcher behind a $timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/3639/

### JS

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("TreeController", ['$scope',function($scope) {


    $scope.menuItems = [{
      "isNavItem": true,
      "href": "#/dashboard.html",
      "text": "Dashboard"
    }, {
      "isNavItem": true,
      "href": "javascript:;",
      "text": "AngularJS Features",
      "subItems": [{
        "href": "#/ui_bootstrap.html",
        "text": " UI Bootstrap"
      }, {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "javascript:;",
        "text": "AngularJS Features",
        "subItems": [{
          "href": "#/ui_bootstrap.html",
          "text": " UI Bootstrap"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "isNavItem": true,
      "href": "javascript:;",
      "text": "jQuery Plugins",
      "subItems": [{
        "href": "#/form-tools",
        "text": " Form Tools"
      }, {
        "isNavItem": true,
        "href": "javascript:;",
        "text": " Datatables",
        "subItems": [{
          "href": "#/datatables/managed.html",
          "text": " Managed Datatables"
        }]
      }]
    }];
  }]);
```

### HTML

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <a href="{{item.href}}" ng-class="{'nav-link nav-toggle': item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0}">
      <span class="title">{{item.text}}</span>
    </a>
    <ul ng-if="item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0" class="sub-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="item in item.subItems" ng-class="{'start': item.isStart, 'nav-item': item.isNavItem}" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
  </script>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" ng-class="{'page-sidebar-menu-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}">
      <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-class="{'start': item.isStart, 'nav-item': item.isNavItem}" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```