# JavaScript/Angularjs - View a template according to a JSON configuration, multiple ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML template to display according to a config the return of a JSON configuration

JSON config :

```
[
  {
    label: 'Type of contact',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Type of prospect',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'Seller'
          },
          {
            label: 'Buyer'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To display it I did :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.filtersConfig">
  <span>{{ item.label }}</span>

  <div ng-repeat="itemChildren in item.children">
    <ul>{{ itemChildren.label }}
      <div ng-repeat="itemChildrenOfChildren in itemChildren.children">
        <li>{{ itemChildrenOfChildren.label }}</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

it works but the problem is that I can have several levels of depth with `children`, if I ever have 10 depth levels with`children` I will have to do 10 ng-repeat

Do you have ideas of how to handle this with more dynamic ways ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursion with ng-repeat in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785885/recursion-with-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: I remembered I wrote a tree structure a while ago using recursion since angularjs (> 1.x (x=5 or 6?)) supports recursion. You can do something similar use ng-content to include child content.

Comment: @George noted, I didn't knew that

Comment: @ABOS I am on the 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a component to display a child and its children. For each child, the component can use itself to display the child and **its** children. If there are several nested layers of children performance will quickly become an issue, but you could limit devise a way to limit the levels displayed. Here's an idea that will handle it with a single `ng-repeat` in your view no matter how many levels of children there are:

Use this at the top level:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ topLevelObject.label }}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="child in topLevelObject.children">
                <child-display display-object="child"></child-display>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**childDisplay.js**

```
angular.module('app') // assumes an app has already been registered
  .component('childDisplay', {
    bindings: {
      displayObject: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: 'childDisplay.html'
  });
```

**childDisplay.html**

```
{{ $ctrl.displayObject.label }}
<ul ng-if="$ctrl.displayObject.children && $ctrl.displayObject.children.length > 0">
  <li ng-repeat="child in $ctrl.displayObject.children">
    <child-display display-object="child"></child-display>
  </li>
</ul>
```