# How to bind tree structure to accordion or list(li) using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How to bind tree structure to accordion using angular. The tree structure is like parent and child. How to get this? Am able to bind complete list.

angular code:

```
 $scope.groups = [
      {
          ID: 1,
          Name: "parent",
          ParentID:0
      },
      {
          ID: 2,
          Name: "child",
          ParentID: 1

      },
      {
          ID: 3,
          Name: "subchild1",
          ParentID: 2

      },
       {
          ID: 4,
          Name: "subchild2",
          ParentID: 2

      }
    ];
```

view:
i tried to bind  tree to accordion but not getting,

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" ng-repeat="grp in groups" is-open="status.open">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            {{grp.Name}}  <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        {{grp.Name}}
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

is there any options to bind tree in other way either accordion but using angular

Comment: Try This
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108946/how-to-put-ng-repeat-inside-ng-repeat-for-n-number-of-times/37109091#37109091) For manage tree structure in angularJS

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there is a way to bind to this tree in AngularJS! To me this seems like a great use case for [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)! Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in groups"

  <h1> {{value.ID}} </h1>
  <h2> {{value.Name}} </h2>
  <h3> {{value.ParentID}} </h3>

</div>
```

If you want the panels to expand then I would add another property to each object, **isExpanded** (or whatever you want to call it). Then you can hide/show the expanded content with [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in groups"

  <h1> {{value.ID}} </h1>
  <h2> {{value.Name}} </h2>
  <h3> {{value.ParentID}} </h3>

  <div ng-if="value.isExpanded === true">
    <h3> Expanded content </h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

You could also have nice animated transitions for expanded and closing the div with [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).

You could also check out [Angular UI-Bootstrap Accordian](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or 
(and here's a codepen example of it: http://codepen.io/funkybudda/pen/vEbgVv)

Here's a plunkr example of an AngularJS accordian: http://embed.plnkr.co/3y0Rq1/

Good luck!