# Consuming JSON Object in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, dictionary

My Spring Rest Controller Endpoint is as below:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/getEverything", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody MyItems getEverything(){
    return myService.getEverything();
}
```

Below is `MyItems` class:

```
public class MyItems {

private Map<String, ArrayList<MyItem>> everything;

public Map<String, ArrayList<MyItem>> getEverything() {
    return everything;
}

public void setEverything(Map<String, ArrayList<MyItem>> everything) {
    this.everything = everything;
}   
}
```

The rest call returns Json in below format:

```
{
"myItems": {
"Office": [
  {
    "field1": "Read a book",
    "field2": "xyz",
    "field3": true,
    "field4": 1489795200000
  },
  {
    "field1": "Write a program",
    "field2": "abc",
    "field3": false,
    "field4": 1489881600000
  }
],
"Home": [
  {
    "field1": "Watch a movie",
    "field2": "pqr",
    "field3": true,
    "field4": 1489797800000
  }
]
}
}
```

Here `Office`, `Home` are keys in the returned map.

How do I iterate or consume this JSon in AngularJS?

How do I get the key values ?

```
 $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI + 'toDo/getAllItems').then(function(response){
     // what will go here ?
     $scope.myItemLists = response.data;
 });
```

I want myItemLists as a List containing objects with two properties:

1) Listname: This will be the key of the map returned.

2) List of Fields: This will be the list of object returned.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to use this JSON? Perhaps showing it in HTML? Use `ng-repeat` directive for it.

Comment: @31piy: Hi.. how? when I use ng-repeat to print key and value, I get key as "myItems" and value as rest whole Json. Which is not what I want. I want keys as Office, Home, etc. and Value as the lists against Office, Home.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. use angular `forEach` loop

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myItems ={
"myItems": {
"Office": [
  {
    "field1": "Read a book",
    "field2": "xyz",
    "field3": true,
    "field4": 1489795200000
  },
  {
    "field1": "Write a program",
    "field2": "abc",
    "field3": false,
    "field4": 1489881600000
  }
],
"Home": [
  {
    "field1": "Watch a movie",
    "field2": "pqr",
    "field3": true,
    "field4": 1489797800000
  }
]
}
}

var keys = [];
var objectValues = [];
 angular.forEach($scope.myItems.myItems,function(value,key){
    keys.push(key);
    objectValues.push(value);
 })
 
     console.log(keys);
    console.log(objectValues);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="aCtrl">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store data in separate variable see below,

```
$http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI + 'toDo/getAllItems').then(function(response){
     // what will go here ?
     $scope.myItemLists = response.data;
     $scope.itemListOfficeData = response.data.myItems.Office;
     $scope.itemListHomeData = response.data.myItems.Home;
 });
```

Or you can use nested `data-ng-repeat` for iterate data see below link for reference.

[Nested ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839743/nested-ng-repeat)

[using ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484686/using-ng-repeat-inside-another-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

While HJz answer is fine if what you want is to iterate through your json data in the controller, but if you simply want to present the data in a view, you can use `ng-repeat` directly on your json object like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in myItems">{{key}}: {{value | json}}</li>
<ul>
```

which roughly turns into the following html *(some values have been ignored for better readability)*:

```
<ul>
    <li>Office: [{"field1": "Read a book"}, {"field1": "Read a book"}]</li>
    <li>Home: [{"field1": "Watch a movie"}]</li>
<ul>
```

You can nest this `ng-repeat` directives, to further iterate through the values in your json data.

---

Alternatively, if all you need is an array of keys or an array of values, then JavaScript got functions you can use to extract those:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myItems); 
// -> ['Office', 'Home']

var values = Object.values(myItems); 
// -> [[{"field1": "Read a book"}, {"field1": "Write a program"}], [{"field1": "Watch a movie"}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the nested object first and then iterate over it or you can use nested ng-repeat as shown below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  var items = {
    "myItems": {
      "Office": [{
          "field1": "Read a book",
          "field2": "xyz",
          "field3": true,
          "field4": 1489795200000
        },
        {
          "field1": "Write a program",
          "field2": "abc",
          "field3": false,
          "field4": 1489881600000
        }
      ],
      "Home": [{
        "field1": "Watch a movie",
        "field2": "pqr",
        "field3": true,
        "field4": 1489797800000
      }]
    }
  }
  $scope.myItems = items.myItems;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(item, fields) in myItems">
      {{item}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="field in fields">
          {{field}}
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(name, value) in field">
              {{name}}:{{value}}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```