# How to set index values to child rows in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement where I need to add index values for child rows. I have Group rows under which there will be child rows. I am `ng-repeat` and I am using `$index` for child's as shown:

HTML code:

```
<table ng-repeat="node in data">
<tr> <td> {{node.groupName}} </td> </tr>
<tbody ng-model="node.nodes">
<tr  ng-repeat="node in node.nodes"> <td> {{$index}} </td> </tr>
</table>
```

But it is displaying as shown:

[image]

But I want it to display as shown:

[image]

I am new to Angular JS and not getting how to display it like this. How am I supposed to do that. Please help.

Comment: It's displaying like that because you are using index.  Index will start over at 0 within each group.  What does your data actually look like?  Is there a reason you are using index instead of actual values?

Comment: @ Rani Radcliff I don't want data to display there. I just want index values to display there as shown above. Is there any other method to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you'd like to have something like that:

```
<table ng-repeat="group in data">
  <thead> 
    <th> {{group.name}} </th> 
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in group.items"> 
    <tr> 
      <td>{{getIndex($parent.$index - 1, $index)}} | {{item}} </td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>

    $scope.data = [
      {name: 'Group1', items: ['a','b']},           
      {name: 'Group2', items: [1,2,3]},
      {name: 'Group3', items: ['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx']}
    ];

    $scope.getIndex = function(previousGroupIndex, currentItemIndex){
      if(previousGroupIndex >= 0){
        var previousGroupLength = getPreviousItemsLength(previousGroupIndex);
        return previousGroupLength + currentItemIndex;
      }
      return currentItemIndex;
    };

    function getPreviousItemsLength(currentIndex){
      var length = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= currentIndex; i++){
        length += $scope.data[i].items.length;
      }
      return length;

      // or even better to use Array.prototype.reduce() for that purpose
      // it would be shorter and beautiful
      // return $scope.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentGroup, index){
      //    return index <= previousGroupIndex ? previousValue + currentGroup.items.length : previousValue;
      // }, 0);
    }
```

You need to play with [$parent.$index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256600/passing-2-index-values-within-nested-ng-repeat) property and use some math :) in order to achieve that.

It would look like the following:

[image]

Check out [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dkdmcq37/) to see live example.

Comment: It is giving values like,  {0,3}, {0,3,5}. But I want like {0,1} , (2,3,4}

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana, please look at my updated answer and perhaps it would need to modify your initial dataset in order to fit in.

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana, does it help?

Comment: @ Artyom Pranovich It's still displaying like {0,3} , {0,3,7)

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana, Have you checked my live example? I've provided you basic idea/alghorythm for your question. But I can not apply it for your code, because I don't have your initial background, exact dataset and so on..

Comment: @ Artyom Pranovich  I will try to apply the similar logic. Thanks so much for the help :)