# Angularjs - in nested ng-repeaters, how do you get index of outher repeater item within nested repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have nested ng-repeaters,, like this

```
<div ng-repeat="outeritem in outerobject">

    <div ng-repeat="inneritem in innerobject" ng-click="function(inneritem.key, $index)"></div>

<div>
```

How would I get the `$index` from **outterobject** repeater in `function(inneritem.key, $index)` which is in `ng-click` directive of **innerobject** repeater?

### Update:

I ended up using this approach although there are two other good ones mentioned in below posts.

```
<div ng-repeat="(indexvalue, outeritem) in outerobject">

    <div ng-repeat="inneritem in innerobject" ng-click="function(inneritem.key, indexvalue)"></div>

<div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$parent` to access the scope of parent element.

```
ng-click="function(inneritem.key, $parent.$index)"
```

Comment: @ng-jslearningcurve Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807258 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256600

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I ended up using '(indexVar, valueVar) in values' that was a few answers below in the post you pointed me to. That looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Warning. Using `$parent` is not a good practice - it breaks the encapsulation, hard to test, your code is not stable under change - all sort of bad things.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ng-init` is the most robust method, if done right:

```
<div ng-repeat = "outerItem in outerObject" 
     ng-init = "outerIndex=$index">

    <div ng-repeat = "innerItem in innerObject" 
         ng-click = "expression($index, outerIndex)"></div>

<div>
```

Here `ng-init` grabs the value of `$index` on the outer scope created by the outer `ng-repeat` directive.

The same way you can use `ng-init` to grab any value on the correct scope.
So the other answer putting `ng-init` next to the second `ng-repeat` would grab the index of that second repeater, not the outer one!

The usual scope inheritance caveaut applies - any other expression defining `outerIndex` on a child scope will not change the one of the parent scope. Use *object property* such as `outer.Index` instead, to avoid this effect.

This approach is also more robust as it will survive under code changes affecting `$parent` scopes, e.g. by wrapping the interior repeater into any directive affecting scope hierarchy (such as `ng-repeat`).

It is also easy to test (which e.g. any code using `$parent` isn't).

---

Note that [Angular official documentation for `ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) considers this to be "the only appropriate use of it":

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than `ngInit` to `initialize` values on a scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-init and set it explicitly

```
<div ng-repeat="outeritem in outerobject">

    <div ng-init='outerindex=$index' ng-repeat="inneritem in innerobject" ng-click="function(inneritem.key, outerindex)"></div>

<div>
```

Comment: Which would you think would be prudent to do? Use parent OR this method?

Comment: I ended up using '(indexVar, valueVar) in values' that @CodeHater suggested. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: This way `outerindex` becomes the inner index, not the outer!