# Distinguish between $index in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two ng-repeats, one inside the other.

```
     <table ng-repeat="all in values track by $index">
        <tr ng-repeat = "errors in all track by $index">
         // I want to use the $index of both ng-repeats 
        </tr>
     </table>
```

I have to use the $index of both the ng-repeats. How can I distinguish one $index from the other?

Comment: Have you checked this question? I think it may cover you :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807258/access-index-of-the-parent-ng-repeat-from-child-ng-repeat?rq=1

Comment: you can use $parent.$index for table and $index for tr in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `$parent.$index` for getting the parents index:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="data in parent track by $index">
            <div ng-repeat="data1 in data track by $index">
                {{$parent.$index}}:{{$index}}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where myApp is:

```
angular
   .module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.parent = [
        ['a','e','i','o','u'],
        ['a1','e1','i1','o1','u1'],
        ['a2','e2','i2','o2','u2'],     
    ];
});
```

You can have a look at more details in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kejozureru/edit?html,js,output).