# How to access the index of super parent in nested ng-repeats

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to access the index of the outermost ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="">
  <div ng-repeat="">
    <div ng-repeat="">
      //I want to get the $index of outer ng-repeat here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access index of the parent ng-repeat from child ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807258/access-index-of-the-parent-ng-repeat-from-child-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-init` to set the outer index:

```
<div ng-repeat="" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
```

Then you can use `outerIndex` in the other scopes.

[Angular documentation has this example specifically](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: up +1 for actual use case from angular doc

Answer (score 0):

A nice clean way to do this is with [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

```
<div ng-repeat="" ng-init="indxFirst = $index">
 <div ng-repeat="" ng-init="indxSecond = $index">
   <div ng-repeat="">
       //the current index $index
      //indxFirst is your the parent most index
      <div ng-click="myClick(indxFirst)">Check most outer parent index</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So, for example I added a click function and passed it inside the inner most repeat, and in the controller you would see it passed here like :

```
$scope.myClick = function(index){
   console.log("parent most index is", index);
};
```

Can use it however you like, this is just an example.