# access ng-repeat $index from a inner ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, foreach, angularjs-ng-repeat

Knowing that ng-repeat create a scope, how do I access the `$index` of a parent ng-repeat from a child `ng-repeat`?

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="first in arr">
   here there is the first level $index
   <div ng-repeat="second in first.arr">
         in here I need access to the first level $index
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the index of super parent in nested ng-repeats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006962/how-to-access-the-index-of-super-parent-in-nested-ng-repeats)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever `ng-repeat` iterate to create a DOM, it also does create a DOM, with new scope which prototypically inherited from the current running scope.

As you wanted to access the `ng-repeat` $index of outer `ng-repeat` in inner `ng-repeat`, you could use `$parent.$index` to indicate parent `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="first in arr">
   here there is the first level $index
   <div ng-repeat="second in first.arr">
         in here I need access to the first level {{$parent.$index}}
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Though the cleaner solution to solve this problem would be, use `ng-init` on outer `ng-repeat` and have outer `index` in scope variable, by which you can get rid of `$parent` keyword.

```
<div ng-repeat="first in arr" ng-init="parentIndex=$index">
   here there is the first level $index
   <div ng-repeat="second in first.arr">
         in here I need access to the first level {{parentIndex}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cleaner solution is to use ng-init, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006962/how-to-access-the-index-of-super-parent-in-nested-ng-repeats

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="first in [1,2,3]">
 here there is the first level {{$index}}
 <div ng-repeat="second in ['a', 'b', 'c']">
     in here I need access to the first level {{$parent.$index}} / {{$index}}
 </div>
```

Output:

```
here there is the first level 0
in here I need access to the first level 0 / 0
in here I need access to the first level 0 / 1
in here I need access to the first level 0 / 2
here there is the first level 1
in here I need access to the first level 1 / 0
in here I need access to the first level 1 / 1
in here I need access to the first level 1 / 2
here there is the first level 2
in here I need access to the first level 2 / 0
in here I need access to the first level 2 / 1
in here I need access to the first level 2 / 2
```