# Angular.js : Dynamic length of columns in table

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I am new to Angular and have been trying to make a dynamic table.

The user enters the no of columns he wants and then he can add as many rows to **each** column as he wants.

I have provided an "add" button at the end of each column to add new row to that particular column.

My code looks somewhat like this:

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="x in setno"> SET {{x.number}}</th>
    </tr>
  
  <tr ng-repeat="z in selected">
    <td> </td>
    </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="x in setno"> 
       <button ng-click="selected.push({})"> add </button>
    </td>
    </tr>
  
</table>
```

where, **setno** is list containing numbers:

```js
$scope.setno[{id:"a", number:"1"},{id:"b", number:"2"},...];
```

and **selected** has a similar structure.

The problem is that when I click "*add*" button of any column, a new row gets add to all the columns.

Whereas I want, a new row to be added to only the one whose "*add*" button has been clicked.

**How can I know whose "*add*" button has been clicked?**

Answer (score 0):

> How can i know whose "add" button has been clicked?

You need access to the current `$index` of the target *repeater*.  Now I'm not sure which it is you're trying to target but you can store an `ng-repeater`'s `$index` as another variable for access from inner repeaters using the following syntax:

```
<!-- outer loop -->
<div ng-repeat="(idxA, item) in items)">

    <!-- inner loop -->
    <div ng-repeat"(idxB, obj) in item.objs">

         <ul>
             <!-- another inner loop -->
             <li ng-repeat="li in obj.pts">
```

In the above code `idxA` will be the same as the outer loop's `$index`, `idxB` is the inner loop's `$index` and so on.  Then you just pass the *index* (e.g. `idxA` or `idxB`) to your method.

resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18914958/1121919
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat