# $index in angularjs in not giving proper output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have edited the question as it became too long
Hi I have this angular code :

```
var mod = angular
            .module("myMod",[])
            .controller("myCont",function($scope){
              var obj = [
              {name : "Monica", others :[{age:20},{salary:20000}]},
              {name : "Rachel", others :[{age:16},{salary:28000}]},
              {name : "Pheobe", others :[{age:24},{salary:30000}]}
              ]
              $scope.obj1 = obj;
             })
```

and this html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html  >
    <head> 
        <script src = "angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "angularmy.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myMod" ng-controller="myCont">
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li ng-repeat="item in obj1" ng-init="parentIndex=$index">{{item.name}} 
                <ol ng-repeat="items in item.others">
                    <li >{{items.age }} parentIndex - {{parentIndex}} index - {{$index}}</li>
                    <li >{{items.salary }} parentIndex - {{parentIndex}} index - {{$index}}</li>
                </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it is giving the index of the second nested list item also 0 :

1. Monica

   1. 20 parentIndex - 0 index - 0
   2. parentIndex - 0 index - 0
   3. parentIndex - 0 index - 1
   4. 20000 parentIndex - 0 index - 1
2. Rachel

   1. 16 parentIndex - 1 index - 0
   2. parentIndex - 1 index - 0
   3. parentIndex - 1 index - 1
   4. 28000 parentIndex - 1 index - 1
3. Pheobe

   1. 24 parentIndex - 2 index - 0
   2. parentIndex - 2 index - 0
   3. parentIndex - 2 index - 1
   4. 30000 parentIndex - 2 index - 1

Could someone please let me know what is wrong in this code ? Why four outputs are coming instead of 2 ???

Comment: It is showing correct indexes. Its the same iteration hence value is same.

Comment: I believe your logic is wrong, code is doing what it needs to do.

Comment: Here is a sample that should 2 iterations [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/oeas1vs9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ol  ng-repeat="items in item.others track by $index">
   <li>{{items.age}} parentIndex - {{parentIndex}} index - {{$index}}</li>
   <li>{{items.salary}} parentIndex - {{parentIndex}} index - {{$index}}</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is not going to help, since OP has only 1 object inside, so `$index` will always have `0` value

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807258/access-index-of-the-parent-ng-repeat-from-child-ng-repeat) what you want to accomplish is:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in obj1">{{item.name}} 
    <ol ng-repeat="o in item.others">
        <li>{{o.age}} parentIndex - {{$parent.$index}} index - {{$index}}</li>
        <li>{{o.salary}} parentIndex - {{$parent.$index}} index - {{$index}}</li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: I know how to get the parent's name. What I do not understand is how array in the controller can be accessed and also when the objects in the array object are different then also it is giving some weird output.

Comment: @YepMe I think your variable names are not helping, check my edited answer, in `item` you have all the data from the `obj1`, like the name you just mentioned, but in the second `ng-repeat` you can access in `o` all the properties of the `others` **array**, that is why you can see "age" and "salary" being repeated. The important part that I wanted to show you is that the current index for our `ng-repeat` is `$index` and the index of the parent `ng-repeat` can be accessed via `$parent.$index`, that is all...

Comment: If you check even I had done that items.age and items.salary

Comment: I dont reall know what are you asking for and what specific problem do you have, for me the example is cristal clear and there is no possible question about it.

Comment: You should really consider choosing more helpful variable names to use in your `ng-repeat`s.

Answer (score 0):

To help you visualise what you are displaying, you should really consider using more helpful variable names in your ng-repeats, especially when they start nesting.

Controller:

```
var mod = angular
.module("myMod",[])
.controller("myCont",function($scope){
  var obj = [
    {name : "Monica", others :[{age:26,salary:20000}]},
    {name : "Rachel", others :[{age:28,salary:28000}]},
    {name : "Pheobe", others :[{age:29,salary:30000}]}
  ]
  $scope.obj1 = obj;
})
```

Template:
(here i've replaced the `ol` with `ul` to avoid another potential source of confusion)

```
<body ng-app="myMod" ng-controller="myCont">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in obj1" >Name: {{person.name}} | Person Index: {{$index}}
            <ul ng-repeat="detail in person.others">
                <li>Age: {{detail.age}} | Salary: {{detail.salary}} | Index: {{$index}} | Parent Index: {{$parent.$index}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

You biggest issue was that you had 2 x `li`s inside of your 2nd ng-repeat.

Output:

```
Name: Monica | Person Index: 0
Age: 26 | Salary: 20000 | Index: 0 | Parent Index: 0
Name: Rachel | Person Index: 1
Age: 28 | Salary: 28000 | Index: 0 | Parent Index: 1
Name: Pheobe | Person Index: 2
Age: 29 | Salary: 30000 | Index: 0 | Parent Index: 2
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7uva6rgt/2/

Comment: Thanks but I was able to access the values when the object was like this:
{name : "Monica", others :[{age:26,salary:20000}]},
    {name : "Rachel", others :[{age:28,salary:28000}]},
    {name : "Pheobe", others :[{age:29,salary:30000}]}

But when it is like below I am not able to access it properly. Others have two objects with different keys.
     '{name : "Monica", others :[{age:20},{salary:20000}]},
     {name : "Rachel", others :[{age:16},{salary:28000}]},
     {name : "Pheobe", others :[{age:24},{salary:30000}]}'

Comment: I didn't change anything in your data object.

Comment: Thanks again but kindlynote you are accessing "[{age:26,salary:20000}]" and I am trying to access "[{age:26},{salary:20000}]"